# Ample disk space with error: "1034 Incorrect key file for table 'table_name'; try to repair it"

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I'm attempting to alter a 1.6 GB InnoDB table with the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `field_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
```

The query fails with the following error:

```
1034 Incorrect key file for table 'table_name'; try to repair it
```

Nearly every thread on this topic (SO and elsewhere) suggests that this is due to the tmpdir running out of space.

**While this seems to be the problem for many, this doesn't seem to be the case on our system.**

`tmpdir` is `/tmp`:

[image]

`/tmp` is far from full:

[image]

**I'm totally stuck.  Thoughts?**

Comment: Also, `df -i` reveals that `/tmp` is only using 1% of its inodes.

Comment: how You check the table size? how much space it use on disk - ls -l mysql_data/db_folder?

Answer (score 7):

Well, I'm a big dummy.  When I went to check the size of the database via the method requested by @a_vlad, I realized that previously **I was checking the free space on `/tmp` on the wrong server**.

Gah.  Executing the command again while tracking the free space on `/tmp` on the correct server reveals that lack of free space is, indeed, the problem.

...and here's the slice of humble pie I'm eating right now:

[image]

Comment: Upvote for the photo.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be different.  When using MyISAM, almost any non-graceful shutdown leads to some tables needing "repair".  This is an important reason to switch to InnoDB.

```
CHECK TABLE `table_name`;
```

That will probably say that it needs repairing, then do

```
REPAIR TABLE `table_name`;
```

After that, you can proceed with your `ALTER`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem - the table already uses InnoDB... :/

Comment: Anything in `mysqld.err`?